# Include JavaScript file in another JavaScript file on a local drive

Tags: javascript

I have seen many ways to include a JS file in another JS file, but all of them seem to require the files to be located on a server, as opposed to on the local drive. Is there any way to include a JS file in another while keeping all files on the local drive?

Comment: In what sort of environment is the code running? A browser running a local HTML file? Node?

Comment: It is running in a local HTML file, but functions from the included js file will be needed in the other, so adding another <script> tag with a different src will not work

Comment: It should, have you tried it? Just make sure the scripts run in the correct order. Yeah, it's not so intuitive, but top-level variables in one script file will be accessible by any other script file.

Comment: ah, it seems i made a typo in the file name, classic programming mistake, it does now work

Comment: And that my friend is why we love copy paste so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html file, add 2 script tags, with the src property of the top one being to one you want to include in the other

```html
<script src="include.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
```